# Perl Win32::GuiTest

Tags: perl, winapi

I have a small application with a couple of edit fields. These fields have a property name.
I try to get the windows handle for this object, using the Perl module [`Win32::GuiTest`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest) with the function call

```
@handle = FindWindowLike( undef, undef, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.2bf8098_r11_ad1")
```

I'm getting an array of handles from all edit objects. Does anybody know how I can select the unique ID for a given name? I can't give the name as a parameter, only the windows name.

Comment: `GetWindowID($window)` ?

Comment: Thanx, but GetWindowId requires the dynamic window handle. I'm looking for a function or solution, which takes a statix parameter like a name and supplys the dynamic window handle.